# Python OOP, Class and Instance

Tags: python, oop

I'm currently learning Python in OOP,
I have a question about using list as a class attribute. The question is when I change something in objects it will also change that class attribute.

```
class Backet:
   number_of_stone = 0
   stone_collection = []
   
   def __init__(self,name):
      self.name = name
      self.number_of_stone +=1
      self.stone_collection.append(self.name)

stone_one = Backet('One')
stone_two = Backet('Two')
```

When I print out the `stone_one` and `stone_two.number_of_two` they are = 1 (I know this is correct). But when I print `stone_one` and `stone_two.stone_collection` they both give a list `["One","Two"]`.

My question is that should it be `stone_one.stone_collection = ['One']` and `stone_two.stone_collection = ['Two']`

Comment: Class attribute like `stone_collection` is the same for all instances of the class and since it's also mutable (list), each instance will change the core object which will affect all other instances.

Comment: ```stone_collection``` is a class variable. A class variable is defined inside the class but no inside any method. A class variable is shared for all instances of the class

Comment: Why are you making `number_of_stone = 0` anf `stone_collection = []` class variables?

Answer (score 1):

Change `stone_collection` to instance variable:

```
class Backet:
   def __init__(self, name):
      number_of_stone = 0
      stone_collection = []
      self.name = name
      self.number_of_stone +=1
      self.stone_collection.append(self.name)

stone_one = Backet('One')
stone_two = Backet('Two')
```